# Is it possible to separate gateway function from router?

Tags: router, gateway

A gateway is an entry to another network, usually router device play the gateway function as well.

1. Is it possible that router delegate the gateway function to a device in the LAN and make it to be the gateway? Then the appointed device takes all the responsibility to communicate with the outside world.
2. If a router loses the gateway function, can it still be caller router? will it become a switch?
3. In which business scenario, this design will be chosen?

[image]

Comment: This diagram looks like a NAT gateway in aws.

Comment: Routers route packets between networks. Devices that do that are routers. Even layer-3 switches have a router built in. The process of forwarding packets between networks is called routing, and that is done by a router.

Comment: The difference you seem to make is "a router forwards within private LAN and a gateway routes to/from the rest of the world". That distinction doesn't exist - forwarding by IP address is routing and a router between networks is a gateway. The private/public addressing edge requires NAT for IPv4 but it does not for IPv6.

Answer (score 1):

A *nat gateway* is a term that Amazon made up. It’s not the same meaning used in traditional routing.

Comment: for the traditional routing, the scenario described in diagram doesn't exist. And if the router loses the gateway function, it can't be called router anymore. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: I think you're forcing a precise definition on a term that doesn't have one.  There really isn't a "gateway function".